# action: specifier Task C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

While I was working with *Tasks* I come across this syntax:

```
class Program
{
    static void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(action: TestMethod); // Why this action: specifier
        t.Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If I remove the action keyword, the compiler give me an error message that say :

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)' and
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Func)'

Actually, it's weird to get this kind of message since we don't have a return `Type` for the method that we pass, thus it should be treated as `Action` instead of `Func<>`.

I know there are many other ways to fix that error like casting to `Action` or anonymous method. However, I can't understand where does this `action:` come from and it's working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *named arguments*. It a feature of the c# language which allows to specify the arguments of a function call in an arbitrary order by specifing their name. For more information see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx]. In your case it makes the call of `Run` unique, because only the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(System.Action)` variant has a parameter called *action*.

Comment: well I agree that it's a named argument, but in our case we only have to pass one parameter the action. And we can pass it without specifying the name, hence why the code did dipslay error message when not using it ?

Comment: As the error message states there are two versions of the Run method accepting one argument. Since the passed argument is neither of type System.Func nor of type System.Action but can be converted to both types, it is not clear for the compiler which version to take. But if the passed argument is named it becomes clear, since only the argument of the System-Action version of Run is called *action*.

Answer (score 0):

`action:` is the name of the parameter. Here, you are basically telling the compiler : here is something, now I want you to put it in the parameter that's called 'action'. Since in this case the 2 methods don't have the same parameter name, the compiler is able to understand which one you want to call, hence why you get the error without it.

Side note : this can also be used to give parameters out of order when calling a function, or to specify only some optional parameter while ignoring the other ones before. Pretty cool feature sometimes.